# How to prompt to install .NET Framework when deploying a WPF Browser Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, xbap

Is there any way to make a WPF Browser Application prompt to install .NET Framework with ClickOnce like a regular installable WPF Application?.

Those publishing options are locked when the HostInBrowser property in the project file is set to True, which is necessary for the application i'm developing, however i need to make the installation of dependencies user friendly, and possibly from the .net framework installer already hosted in my server, as it would cut down greatly the use of bandwidth. 
The program is intended to be used in intranet, as a "web page", by placing shortcuts on the desktop of each computer (which is done at the first run of the app), but most of the users don't have .NET Framework 4 installed.

is there any way to accomplish this without converting it to an installable wpf application?

Thanks in advance, Jesús.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749404.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No [ClickOnce requires the .Net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx), because it's a component of it.

> All ClickOnce applications require that the correct version of the .NET
>   Framework is installed on a computer before they can be run

You can however set a prerequisite which is a higher version of the framework, provided they have at least version 2.0 to begin with.

Commonly a bootstrapper written in managed code is used to overcome this limitation. You could use [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for this, [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/), or other third party tools. I've used dotNetInstaller a few times a recommend it, it's very flexible.